# Neo4j Java api cannot get relationship by full-text index in relationship types

Tags: java, indexing, neo4j, relationship

I want to count the relationships by type in Neo4j using neo4j native java Api (not execute Cyper statement)

I create a full-text index in relationships by calling procedure

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createRelationshipIndex(
  "dependsTypeRelationshipIndex",
  ["DEPENDS"], ["isoptional"], 
  { analyzer: "standard", eventually_consistent: "true" })
```

The index has been created suffcessfully :
[image]

Also, there are existing correspondingly relationships :
[image]

However, when I using neo4j native api, it does not work.
[image]

Is there any config I need to set, or method to count the relationships by type without using Cypher?

Comment: How do you define "does not work", is there any error logs?

Comment: @Litchy Well, no error log, but the IndexHits<Relationship> size is supposed to be over 0 while it is 0 in the last picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In neo4j 3.5.*, for the relationship, there are two types of index, explicit index and full-text index. However, in the neo4j java native API, there is only an index manager for the explicit index, which is the reason I can't get my full-text index. So I can only query the full-text index by using the Cypher statement which is a conflict to my condition.

I hope there will be an index manager for the full-text index in the future neo4j java native API.